# Include a line break in a text input

Tags: javascript, css, input, jquery-ui-slider

I use `input type="text"` for the output range of a JS UI Slider(works only with input type="text"), but I want to give it some styling.

For example after 3 characters, I would like a comma and a line break, as in the left image here:

[image: example of ideal output]

This is my code at present:

```
<input type="text" id="amount1" readonly style="position: absolute;">
```

Comment: for me it is unclear question. Please brief it

Comment: how get i make the right one number to look like the left one.It is <input type="text" >

Comment: I've attempted to improve the English of this, but am not completely sure that I have got the meaning correct - feel free to edit further if necessary.

Comment: That won’t work with an input type=text. Just use a “normal” HTML element for the output, that you can format any way you like. If you eventually need the selected value to be send with a form or something like that, then put it into a hidden input field as well.

Comment: my JS UI Slider works only with input type="text"

Comment: What does the slider represent?

Comment: that is a range slider

Comment: Is that possible with something like that ....replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join("")); ?  but i don't know how exactly. Input type="text" after 3digs -  join comma.